# Sonata Admin Create Page Like Settings

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am using sonata admin as my backend, and there is a list of the modules(services) here.

[image]

When I clicked on left side menu links, it will redirect me to listing page.

Now I have one module in where I do not want listing page, but I want a page like below where I can directly have the fields and update the values in the database everytime same as the setting page. Where I can have the columns just I update the values.

[image]

Please enlighten me for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu in Sonata Admin is based on KNP Menu. So depending on what you really need to add there are some ways to customise it using:

- custom controller
- menu provider
- extending the menu

Details in the [docs](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is doing by your way also and i create one custom route and make action in controller and did that thing.